# Assign player currentLocation based on array coordinates

Tags: c#, console

I wanted to incorporate changing location in an rpg, so I began by creating a class Location and assign every Location to a multi-dimensonal array, like so:

```
WorldMap[0, 0] = new Location("Majula");
```

I created two int variables named LocationY and LocationX set to the starting location. Now I got a command handler, when I type "Move South", I update the position with this dead simple code:

```
LocationY++;
```

Mind you, this is just for testing purposes, I just like to break a game into many small components that gets added as I get, or know better.

Now when I want to get my current location, I call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("He then headed south, until he arrived at {0}", WorldMap[PlayerLocationY, PlayerLocationX].Name);
```

That's cool and all, and it works, but I don't like typing too much if I can avoid it, so I wanted to change the call of `WorldMap[PlayerLocationY, PlayerLocationX].Name` to something more readable like `currentLocation.Name`.

So I tried this bit of code:

```
Location currentLocation = WorldMap[PlayerLocationY, PlayerLocationX];
```

Obviously, I get a NullReferenceException... I'm completely clueless, and I'm sure I'll probably say to myself "duh" when I'll get an answer.

And yeah, still learning, Console still rocks my socks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a [C# Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx?) with a getter:

```
Location currentLocation
{
   get 
   {
       return WorldMap[PlayerLocationY, PlayerLocationX]; 
   }
}
```

Put this in the body of your class, along with the declarations for member variables like `WorldMap` and the player's coordinates. [You can add an access modifier if you want it to be public or protected.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms173121.aspx)

Now when you write something like `currentLocation.Name`, it will call this `get` function internally, return the requested value from the `WorldMap`, and then dig out the `Name` of that returned location.

(Note: this will still give you a NullReferenceException if either your WorldMap is undefined or lacks an entry at this X,Y coordinate - so make sure your data is properly initialized!)